# Ios custom circle sliders

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I wanted to use circle slider(not the default linear slider) in my app .I should do it manually or is that any ios function that i can use??

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a standard circular slider / dial built into iOS - linear sliders are preferred in standard UIs as they make effective use of screen real-estate.

Answer (score 0):

There's no dial controller in the official iPhone SDK that I know of. But do some Google searching and you might find something open source.

I see other people have been [wrestling with the same issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615021/core-animation-difficulties-with-spinning-dial-control-very-detailed).